# Problem after deployed backend on render. Data fatching after 1 mint

Tags: deployment, backend

I have deployed my backend  on render .When i visit my website first time it will take 1to 2mint delay to connecting with backend and fatching.
and when i see in render logs it is restarting nodejs server and connecting databse.

and after render all content. it is working smooth . if i closed that website for 1hr it is behaving same i have to wait 1 mint.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94FHp.png)

please solve my problem